# Docker container is running but cant find the url

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

My name is Omar. I have a docker container that is currently running. Now I want to go online and see if the docker container is actually running without any issue. I am running the following lines of code and when i run the container, it gives a long pause without anything popping up in my linux terminal. How can I go on my web browser and actually see if my container is running:

```
(MySplit) omars-mbp:mysplit omarjandali$ docker build -t test_4 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  56.04MB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3
 ---> 79e1dc9af1c1
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR tab/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4d9f321d66ee
Step 3/6 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4def3e385cef
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a486e74d993d
Step 5/6 : COPY . .
 ---> 9a8336fb3f2e
Step 6/6 : CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
 ---> Running in baa2d48f3714
Removing intermediate container baa2d48f3714
 ---> 49bf417aeb90
Successfully built 49bf417aeb90
Successfully tagged test_4:latest
```

Then i ran the following code:

```
(MySplit) omars-mbp:mysplit omarjandali$ docker run -d -p8000:80 test_4
af875ce118423a8b35b7843127b572c47427a0891a8a0a768a1625367ec315aa
(MySplit) omars-mbp:mysplit omarjandali$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                  NAMES
af875ce11842        test_4              "python manage.py ru…"   8 seconds ago       Up 11 seconds                   0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   frosty_carson
```

How can i access the running container on my web browser to see if it is working properly before pushing it to dockerhub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your build logs below:-

`Step 6/6 : CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`

you are running the server on port `8000`

so to run the things perfectly you need to do things like below for running the container using our image:-

`docker run -d -p <port>:8000 test_4`

here `<port>` will be dynamic, you can choose it yourself, as per your needs and after that, it should be available at `http://localhost:<port>`

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to port 8000 on the host machine. `-p 8000:80` means to map host port 8000 to container port 80. Possibly you meant the other way around, i.e. map host port 80 to container port 8000 in which case run the command with `-p 80:8000`

Comment: so would the url be 127.0.0.1... a long time ago when i got it working. it have me and extension. something like 127.0.0.1:32678 or something like that... it is not doing that right now...

Comment: what would put in the url i ran it the other way around like you suggested and it didnt change anything...

Comment: `http://localhost:8000` for the first command. `http://localhost` for the second.  I assume that the host is public facing so it should be `-p 80:8000` if your django server is listening on port 8000 in the container. You might also like to map the SSL port 443 too so that https works.

Comment: I tried localhost:8000 and it said the site is not working. same with the second one...

Answer (score 0):

How about accessing directly the container's IP?

When ip is taken by:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' [CONTAINER-NAME]
192.168.###.###
```

then, the URL is "http://192.168.###.###:8000"